# Retrieving listbox values in action class

Tags: java, jsp

I have two listboxes in my jsp where in I am dynamically retrieving values for the first listbox based on the previous dropdown selection made by the user. The user will then have an option to move selected values from first listbox to the second. I want to retrieve the values of second listbox in my action class. I tried the following but didn't succeed. Please help...

> String[] listbox = request.getParameterValues("ToLB");

Following is my second listbox from which i need to retrieve values,

```
<select multiple size="8" name="ToLB" style="width:278px;" id="customerListToId"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself.. jQuery worked for the above stated problem..